# Выбор сим карты для звонка

Tags: android

Не могу найти решение. Задача показать активность/диалог перед вызовом с возможностью выбора сим1 или сим2. 
То что смог реализовать, но это работает не на всех устройствах.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + call_phone));
        intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", sim); 
        intent.putExtra("slot", sim);
        intent.putExtra("simSlot", sim);
        intent.putExtra("simID", sim);
        intent.putExtra("simId", sim);
        intent.putExtra("subscription", sim);
        intent.putExtra("SlotId", sim);
        intent.putExtra("SLOT_ID", sim);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Так же пробовал

```
try {
            ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
            List<Integer> sims = getInsertedSIMIds(context);
            val.put("value", sims.get(sim));
            context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://settings/system"), val, "name='voice_call_sim_setting'", null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
```

тут вообще без результатов.

Думаю лучший вариант реализации это перед каждым исходящим звонков записывать в системные настройки сим по умолчанию (для вызова) но как это реализовать не совсем понимаю. Любая помощь будет полезна, заранее спасибо.

Нашел еще вот такую информацию но она тоже не работает на моем устройстве

```
/**Where simN is sim card number,
     0 - disable all sim cards radio modules,
     1 - allow only first sim card radio module,
     2 - allow only second sim card radio module,
     3 - allow all sim cards radio module */


        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "dual_sim_mode_setting", 2);
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.DUAL_SIM_MODE");
        localIntent.putExtra("mode", 2);
        context.sendBroadcast(localIntent);
```